# The linear span of the family $\{t^{\lambda_k}\}_{k>=0}$ is dense in $C(X,R)$ with $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\lambda_k} = \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

> Lemma:If $F$ is a bounded holomorphic function on the right half-plane
>   $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:Re(z)>0\}$ such that $F(\lambda_k)=0$ for some
>   increasing sequence of positve numbers such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty
>  \frac{1}{\lambda_k} = \infty \ (*)$, then $F=0$.

Proposition: Let $X=[0,1]$ and $C(X,R)$ is the real-valued continuous functions on X with max norm $ \lVert f \rVert = max_{t\in X} |f(t)|$. 
Let $\lambda_0=0$ and $\{\lambda_k\}_{k>0}$ be an increasing sequence of positive numbers such that $(*)$ holds .  Prove that the linear span of the family $\{t^{\lambda_k}\}_{k>=0}$ is dense in $C(X,R)$.

> Hint: for a given measure $\mu \in M(X,\mathbb{R})$, consider the
>   function $F_\mu(z)=\int_X t^zd\mu(t)$ defined for $z$ in the right
>   half-plane.

Comment: This is the [Müntz–Szász theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCntz%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A1sz_theorem), see for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.3570.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also found a discussion of this in Papa Rudin.